# AWS MediaConvert SQS error about outside resources

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, aws-media-convert

Real Simple. I am getting the error message:

You are not allowed to access resources outside the service 'mediaconvert'

With the USER ARN after it. What am I not understanding about this error? I have given the User full control over S3/SQS/MediaConvert

Answer (score 0):

So, because I was tired and I was not able to think, what I was doing was wrong. When you setup MediaConvert, look in the TOP LEFT CORNER of the main page on AWS, and you will find a menu slideout button, click that, and under there you will find details about the queue you need. You do NOT need to use SQS as the queue.

Lesson Learnt